# OSGi superclass visibility

Tags: java, class, package, osgi

I have a subclass that refers to a superclass in a different package. Do I need to export both packages, to have a bundle refer to and subclass.

example:

```
BundleOne exports packageB
packageA: interface i
packageB: abstract class B implements i

BundleTwo imports packageB
packageC: class C extends B
```

This example doesn't work for me, and osgi framework complains about a missing import package constraint for packageA. I find this strange because I don't refer to it anywhere in class C.

The import-package declarations are being built automatically by a maven plugin, which I think is using bnd behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you absolutely have to export both packages. Why do you think this is strange? You do indeed refer to interface `I` from package `A`, because you refer to class `B` which **is** an `I`.

In fact your class `C` is an `I` as well. To stand a chance of constructing your class, the Java virtual machine must have visibility of the full superclass hierarchy.

Comment: Yea, that's true. I wasn't thinking straight I guess. So I take it, the imports/exports would have to go all the way up, as high as the hierarchy goes.

Comment: Yes. Because all the supertypes and declared interfaces are part of the public signature of the type. They are "used" by the type which is why there are uses constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must export both, the class definition of B has a dependency on A, therefore you cannot reference B without A as well.

This would be a similar to a simple java app in which package A is in **A.jar** and B in **B.jar**.  If at runtime, A.jar is not available then you could not realize B since part of its definition is missing.